# Illustrator: rotating back to perfect angles

Tags: adobe-illustrator, automation

I am wondering:
After I rotate an element in Illustrator to an un-even angle, is there a simple way to rotate it back to an even angle later?

Whenever I try to get a shape back to 0 degrees or 90 degrees, it always seems to be off by a smidgen.

Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

The Subscribe plugin from Astute Graphics has an orient tool for snapping artwork back to right angles, I use it all the time. It also includes some other tools for drawing circles by points, etc. Very useful, and free - http://www.astutegraphics.com/software/subscribe/